# fatal: 'origin/stable-2.10.0' fatal: 'origin / stable-2.10.0' is not a commit and you cannot create a 'dummy' branch from it

Tags: git, github

I would like to pass the integrated GPU from the host os (ubuntu 20.04) to the windows 10 guest os with xen. This is because xen works great for me,better than qemu-kvm for my specific needs and because I have only two graphic cards. The nvidia rtx 2080 ti that I have already passed to the guest,and the intel UHD 630,that can be duplicated from the host to the guest so that it can be used in both places without interruptions. So I'm trying to build this repository :

https://github.com/intel/gvt-linux/wiki/GVTg_Setup_Guide#332-build-qemu--xen-for-xengt

after having fixed a lot of bugs,I think that I've been able to make it work,except for the last bug,that's not strictly related to xen,so I think that this time I'm lucky and you will be able to help me :

```
Install prefix    /usr
BIOS directory    /usr/share/qemu
binary directory  /usr/bin
Manual directory  /usr/share/man
ELF interp prefix /usr/gnemul/qemu-%M
Source path       /etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir
C compiler        gcc
Host C compiler   gcc
ARCH_CFLAGS       -m64
make              make
install           install
host CPU          x86_64
host big endian   no
target list       i386-softmmu x86_64-softmmu arm-softmmu cris-softmmu
m68k-softmmu mips-softmmu mipsel-softmmu mips64-softmmu mips64el-softmmu
ppc-softmmu ppcemb-softmmu ppc64-softmmu sh4-softmmu sh4eb-softmmu
sparc-softmmu i386-linux-user x86_64-linux-user alpha-linux-user
arm-linux-user armeb-linux-user cris-linux-user m68k-linux-user
mips-linux-user mipsel-linux-user ppc-linux-user ppc64-linux-user
ppc64abi32-linux-user sh4-linux-user sh4eb-linux-user sparc-linux-user
sparc64-linux-user sparc32plus-linux-user
gprof enabled     no
sparse enabled    no
profiler          no
static build      no
-Werror enabled   no
SDL support       yes
SDL static link   yes
OpenGL support    yes
curses support    no
mingw32 support   no
Audio drivers     oss
Extra audio cards ac97 es1370 sb16
Mixer emulation   no
VNC TLS support   no
kqemu support     yes
brlapi support    no
Documentation     no
NPTL support      no
vde support       no
AIO support       yes
Install blobs     yes
KVM support       yes
fdt support       no
qemu successfuly configured for Xen qemu-dm build
make[4]: ingresso nella directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote»
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
make[5]: ingresso nella directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
  CC    i386-dm/pass-through.o
  CC    i386-dm/pt-msi.o
  CC    i386-dm/pt-graphics.o
  LINK  i386-dm/qemu-dm
make[5]: uscita dalla directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
make[4]: uscita dalla directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote»
set -e;     export PREFIX="/usr"; export XEN_SCRIPT_DIR="/etc/xen/scripts";
export XEN_ROOT="/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/.."; export CONFIG_BLKTAP1=n; cd
qemu-xen-traditional-dir; make install
make[4]: ingresso nella directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote»
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
make[5]: ingresso nella directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
make[5]: Nessuna operazione da eseguire per «all».
make[5]: uscita dalla directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
mkdir -p "//usr/bin"
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -m0755 -p  qemu-nbd-xen
qemu-img-xen  "//usr/bin"
mkdir -p "//usr/share/xen/qemu"
set -e; for x in bios.bin vgabios.bin vgabios-cirrus.bin ppc_rom.bin
video.x openbios-sparc32 openbios-sparc64 openbios-ppc pxe-ne2k_pci.bin
pxe-rtl8139.bin pxe-pcnet.bin pxe-e1000.bin bamboo.dtb; do \
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -m 644
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir/pc-bios/$x
"//usr/share/xen/qemu"; \
done
mkdir -p "//usr/share/xen/qemu/keymaps"
set -e; for x in da     en-gb  et  fr     fr-ch  is  lt  modifiers  no
 pt-br  sv ar      de     en-us  fi  fr-be  hr     it  lv  nl         pl
 ru     th common  de-ch  es     fo  fr-ca  hu     ja  mk  nl-be      pt
 sl     tr; do \
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -m 644
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir/keymaps/$x
"//usr/share/xen/qemu/keymaps"; \
done
for d in i386-dm; do \
make -C $d install || exit 1 ; \
        done
make[5]: ingresso nella directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
=== PCI passthrough capability has been enabled ===
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -d -m0755 -p
"///usr/lib/xen/bin"
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -d -m0755 -p
"///etc/xen/scripts"
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -m0755 -p
../i386-dm/qemu-ifup-Linux "///etc/xen/scripts/qemu-ifup"
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/cross-install -m0755 -p  qemu-dm
"//usr/lib/xen/bin"
make[5]: uscita dalla directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote/i386-dm»
make[4]: uscita dalla directory
«/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/qemu-xen-traditional-dir-remote»
make[3]: uscita dalla directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools»
make[3]: ingresso nella directory «/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools»
if test -d file://localhost/root/igvtg-xen/igvtg-qemu ; then \
mkdir -p qemu-xen-dir; \
else \
export GIT=git; \
/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../scripts/git-checkout.sh
file://localhost/root/igvtg-xen/igvtg-qemu origin/stable-2.10.0
qemu-xen-dir ; \
fi
Clone in 'qemu-xen-dir-remote.tmp' in corso...
remote: Enumerazione degli oggetti in corso: 361946, fatto.
remote: Conteggio degli oggetti in corso: 100% (361946/361946), fatto.
remote: Compressione oggetti in corso: 100% (66302/66302), fatto.
remote: 361946 oggetti totali (294814 delta), 361928 riutilizzati (294803
delta)
Ricezione degli oggetti: 100% (361946/361946), 125.40 MiB | 50.22 MiB/s,
fatto.
Risoluzione dei delta: 100% (294814/294814), fatto.
 fatal: 'origin/stable-2.10.0' fatal: 'origin / stable-2.10.0' is not a commit and you cannot create a 'dummy' branch from it.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:197: qemu-xen-dir-find] Errore 128
```

the error " fatal: 'origin/stable-2.10.0' fatal: 'origin / stable-2.10.0' is not a commit and you cannot create a 'dummy' branch from it" could be caused by this script ?

```
nano /etc/xen/igvtg-xen/scripts/git-checkout.sh

#!/bin/sh

if test $# -lt 3; then
echo "Usage: $0
"
exit 1
fi

TREE=$1
TAG=$2
DIR=$3

set -e

if test ! -d $DIR-remote; then
rm -rf $DIR-remote $DIR-remote.tmp
mkdir -p $DIR-remote.tmp; rmdir $DIR-remote.tmp
$GIT clone $TREE $DIR-remote.tmp
if test "$TAG" ; then
cd $DIR-remote.tmp
$GIT branch -D dummy >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
$GIT checkout -b dummy $TAG
cd ..
fi
mv $DIR-remote.tmp $DIR-remote
fi
rm -f $DIR
ln -sf $DIR-remote $DIR
```

or in some other file ? how can I fix it ? ask me whatever file you want to look inside and I will show you :D

PS : commenting this line #$GIT checkout -b dummy $TAG

I get the following output :

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/pkg-config \
$source/configure --enable-xen --target-list=i386-softmmu \
     \
    $enable_trace_backend \
    --prefix=/usr/lib/xen \
    --libdir=/usr/lib/xen/lib \
    --includedir=/usr/lib/xen/include \
    --source-path=$source \
    --extra-cflags="-DXC_WANT_COMPAT_EVTCHN_API=1 \
    -DXC_WANT_COMPAT_GNTTAB_API=1 \
    -DXC_WANT_COMPAT_MAP_FOREIGN_API=1 \
    -DXC_WANT_COMPAT_DEVICEMODEL_API=1 \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/toolcore/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/toollog/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/evtchn/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/gnttab/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/foreignmemory/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/devicemodel/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libxc/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/xenstore/include \
    -I/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/xenstore/compat/include \
    " \
    --extra-ldflags="-L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libxc \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/xenstore \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/toolcore \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/evtchn \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/gnttab \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/foreignmemory \
    -L/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/devicemodel \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/toolcore \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/toollog \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/evtchn \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/gnttab \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/call \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/foreignmemory \
    -Wl,-rpath-link=/etc/xen/igvtg-xen/tools/../tools/libs/devicemodel \
    -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/xen/lib" \
    --bindir=/usr/lib/xen/bin \
    --datadir=/usr/share/qemu-xen \
    --localstatedir=/var \
    --disable-kvm \
    --disable-docs \
    --disable-guest-agent \
    --python=python \
     \
    --cpu=x86_64 \
    ; \
make all

ERROR: configure test passed without -Werror but failed with -Werror.
       This is probably a bug in the configure script. The failing command
       will be at the bottom of config.log.
       You can run configure with --disable-werror to bypass this check.
```

Comment: What does it print if you add `echo $GIT checkout -b dummy $TAG`? In the question title, there are spaces around `/`. Is it so for the value of `$TAG`?

Comment: refresh page.....